# Unable to login and load web page in Sony Ericcson W8

Tags: browser, sony-ericsson-w8

I am using a Sony Ericcson w8 Android phone. I am unable to log in and load a web page (like Google, GMail, etc.) even after selecting "clear cache." There is just a blank screen with a progress bar.

Comment: Can you load any web pages? Are you actually connected to the internet at all at the moment? Are you using a 3G connection or a wifi connection?

Comment: well, the similar problem with me -- cant open secure pages through pdanet or easytheter. for example, can open yahoo, but cant access own account...

Answer (score 1):

I assume your selecting Browser > Menu > Settings > Clear Cache ?

You can also try clearing the full app memory from your home screen (outside the browser):

Settings > Applications > Manage Applications > Select the Brower App

Choose 'Clear Data' and also 'Clear Cache'.

If all else fails you could also factory reset the phone.

Comment: It sounds very much like a connection issue, I wouldn't resort to a factory reset before diagnosing the connection.

Comment: Yeah true I assumed he had the sense to realise his net was working. I'll drop my assumptions!